# Small turtle program using instruction strings to draw patterns

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractals, turtle-graphics

A while ago, I wrote a program that combined L-systems and turtles. This was before I understood OOP (I still don't fully understand classes, or if they are even needed here). I tried to add some documentation and included some demos as functions. If I ever get around to it, I hope to include a simple GUI with user-adjustable patterns and parameters (like a typical Java applet).

**Generate L-system**

The inclusion of `V`, the alphabet, is for completeness in the formal description of a L-system as a 3-tuple.

```
import turtle

def l_system(V, w, P, n):
    """Generates an L-system run for n rounds.
    They are defined as
    G = (V, w, P)

    V = The alphabet (tuple, not actually used, can be specified as None)
    w = The start (string)
    P = The production rules (dictionary for replacement)
    """
    # Make sure all production rules are in alphabet
    if V:
        assert(all(key in V for key in P))

    current = w
    for i in range(n):
        current = [P[x] if x in P else x for x in list(current)]
        current = ''.join(current)

    return current
```

**Run the turtle**

```
def run_turtle(var, start, rules, iters, angle, startdir=0):
    """Var, start, rules and iters, correspond to (V, w, P, n) of the 
    l-system function. The distance moved is scaled down from size.
    The turtle starts facing startdir.

    Instructions are defined as the following:
    F, G: Draw forward
    M, N: Move forward (don't draw)
    [, ]: Push and pop angle and location
    +, -: Turn left and right by angle degrees   
    Variables not described can be used as constants.
    """

    # Initialization 
    terry = turtle.Turtle()
    turtle.mode("world") # Coordinate system
    terry.pensize(1)
    terry.pencolor("blue")
    terry.speed(0) # Instant speed
    turtle.tracer(0, 0) # Don't draw anything yet (could change in future)
    turtle.setup(width=900, height=900, startx=None, starty=None) # Square pixels
    terry.hideturtle()


    dist = 1
    positions = []
    angles = []
    bounds = [0, 0, 0, 0] # llx, lly, urx, ury

    instructions = l_system(var, start, rules, iters)
    print("First 50 instructions:\n", instructions[:50])

    def update_bounds(bounds):
        coords = terry.position()

        bounds[0] = min(bounds[0], coords[0])
        bounds[1] = min(bounds[1], coords[1])
        bounds[2] = max(bounds[2], coords[0])
        bounds[3] = max(bounds[3], coords[1])

    # Run turtle
    terry.left(startdir) # Starting direction
    for instr in instructions:
        if instr in ('F', 'G'):
            terry.forward(dist)
            update_bounds(bounds)

        elif instr in ('M', 'N'):
            terry.penup()
            terry.forward(dist)
            terry.pendown()
            update_bounds(bounds)

        elif instr == '[':
            positions.append(terry.pos())
            angles.append(terry.heading())

        elif instr == ']':
            terry.penup()
            terry.goto(positions.pop())
            terry.setheading(angles.pop())
            terry.pendown()

        elif instr == '+':
            terry.left(angle)

        elif instr == '-':
            terry.right(angle)


    llx, lly, urx, ury = bounds
    width = urx - llx
    height = ury - lly

    if width > height: 
        y_center = (ury + lly)/2
        ury = y_center + width/2
        lly = y_center - width/2
    else: 
        x_center = (urx + llx)/2
        urx = x_center + height/2
        llx = x_center - height/2

    print("Bounds:", bounds)
    turtle.setworldcoordinates(llx, lly, urx, ury) # Redraw
    turtle.update() # Draw everything
    turtle.exitonclick()
```

**Demo systems**

Ideally this area could be cleaned up.

```
def right_koch(iters):
    run_turtle(('F',), 'F', {'F':'F+F-F-F+F'}, iters, 90)

def dragon_curve(iters):
    run_turtle(('X', 'Y'), 'FX', {'X':'X+YF', 'Y':'FX-Y'}, iters, 90)

def sierpinski(iters):
    run_turtle(('F', 'G'), 'F', {'F':'G-F-G', 'G':'F+G+F'},  iters, 60)

def plant_1(iters):
    run_turtle(('F', 'G'), 'F', {'G':'GG', 'F':'G[+F]-F'}, iters, 45, startdir=90)

def plant_2(iters):
    run_turtle(('X', 'F'), 'X', {'X':'F-[[X]+X]+F[+FX]-X', 'F':'FF'},
               iters=iters, angle=360-25, startdir=70)

def hilbert_curve(iters):
    run_turtle(('A', 'B'), 'A', {'A':'-BF+AFA+FB-', 'B':'+AF-BFB-FA+'},
               iters=iters, angle=90)

def koch_island(iters):
    run_turtle(('F',), 'F-F-F-F', {'F':'F+FF-FF-F-F+F+FF-F-F+F+FF+FF-F'}, 
               iters=iters, angle=90)

def square_koch(iters):
    run_turtle(('F',), 'F-F-F-F', {'F':'FF-F-F-F-FF'}, iters, 90)

def plant_3(iters):
    run_turtle(('F', 'X'), 'X', {'X':'F[+X]F[-X]+X', 'F':'FF'}, iters,
               20, startdir=90)

def koch_burst(iters):
    # Own design
    run_turtle(('F'), 'F++F++F++F++F', {'F':'F+F--FF++F-F'}, iters, 72,
               startdir=180)


koch_burst(4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the concept of the question (using a domain-specific language to specify a fractal) and your implementation.  An object-oriented rewrite could make it better, but it's not bad as it is.

`l_system()` could be better written as

```
def l_system(V, w, P, n):
    …
    cmd_seq = w
    for _ in range(n):
        cmd_seq = itertools.chain(*(P.get(cmd, cmd) for cmd in cmd_seq))
    return ''.join(cmd_seq)
```

Namely,

- `cmd_seq` would be more meaningful than `current`.  `cmd` would be more meaningful than `x`.
- Use `_` for a variable whose value is disregarded.
- String are directly iterable; you don't have to convert them into lists first.
- Dictionary lookup with a default can be done using `get(key, default)`.
- Instead of re-forming the string with each iteration, just chain them, and join the result just once at the end.

Aside from that, I just have a few minor remarks:

- The parameters are `l_system(V, w, P, n)` but `run_turtle(var, start, rules, iters, …)` — why not use consistent notation?
- As you said, the `l_system()` function doesn't really need `V`.  I would prefer to just leave it out altogether.
- In various places, you refer to the turtle's heading as `terry.heading()`, `startdir`, and `angles`.  I suggest using consistent terminology based on "heading".
- `update_bounds(bounds)` takes a `bounds` array as an explicit parameter, but takes `terry` through its scope chain.  I'd prefer to see either both variables as explicit parameters, or both via the closure.
- Rather than having two separate stacks for `positions` and `angles`, I would prefer to see one `turtle_state` stack that stores `(position, heading)` tuples.
- The epilogue could use a comment, like `# Extend the shorter dimension of the window to make it square`

Comment: Do you think the demo functions are fine the way they are, or could they be modified?

Comment: One thing you could do is add another level of indirection, and put all those demo curve definitions in a dictionary or a config file.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to expect your `var` (or `V`) parameter to contain exactly `P.keys()`.

First of, you could always check that using `assert set(V) == set(P.keys())`, which I find more understandable at first. Also note that `assert` is a keyword, not a function.

Second, and since you don't make use of `V` anyway, you could automate this check without having the user build `V` for you:

- You want every symbol found in `start` and each rewritten rule to be in `"FCMN[]+-" + P.keys()`;
- [Optional] You want every symbol in `P.keys()` to appear in `start` or the rewritten rules so that there is no unused rules;
- [Optional] You want rules to operate on a single-character string, otherwise they won't be used.

You can get rid of both `V` and `var`, and check that, in `l_system` using:

```
assert all(len(R) == 1 for R in P), "Rules need to apply on 1 character only"
key_set = set(P.keys())
rules_set = set(itertools.chain(w, *P.values()))
assert key_set <= rules_set, "{} Rules Unused".format(key_set - rules_set)
key_set.update("FGMN[]+-")
assert rules_set <= key_set, "{} Symbols without Rules".format(rules_set - key_set)
```

Note this is just a rough sketch, you could wrap it in an `if __debug__:` (even if redundant with `assert`) to avoid building sets in optimized mode, you could turn some of them into warning messages with `print("...", file=sys.stderr)` and/or some of them into proper exceptions (possibly `ValueError`).

But the key point here is that you avoid requiring the user to provide two redundant parameters.